# Getting a value with timeout using Kotlin coroutines

Tags: kotlin, coroutines

So, here's a task. A background thread may or may not call all of it's listeners some time after `sendRequest()` was called (in other words `sendRequest()` schedules a possible event). The required function must:

1. Subscribe to those events
2. Call `sendRequest()` periodically until the function returns anything
3. Return the first suitable result (filtering is done in the listener and is omitted in this snippet) or `null` after a timeout
4. Unsubscribe from those events regardless of the result

```
suspend fun findServer(): Server? {
    var listener: ((Server) -> Unit)? = null
    return try {
        withTimeoutOrNull(10000) {
            suspendCancellableCoroutine<Server> { continuation ->
                listener = { server: Server ->
                    continuation.resume(server)
                }.also { discoveryService.addListener(it) }

                launch {
                    while (continuation.isActive) {
                        discoveryService.sendRequest()
                        delay(1000)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    } finally {
        listener?.let { discoveryService.removeListener(it) }
    }
}
```

The current implementation seems to work fine, but the nullable `listener` variable feels kind of clunky and requires using `also` to keep the listener reference, which in turn breaks type inference and makes me specify listener's parameter type (no big deal, but...). I could use a lateinit var here, but it probably can lead to exceptions when `withTimeoutOrNull()` stops before the listener was initialized.

Any recommendations on improving this snippet? Or am I, in fact, doing everything totally wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

Think it's pretty good and you can't think of much else. Some tiny bits I can think of:

- Make `discoveryService` parameter.
- Do not use `launch` without specifying CoroutineScope.

Comment: Well, the application is built on dependency injection and `discoveryService` is an injected component so it shouldn't be a parameter.

I'm not too comfortable with CoroutineScopes yet, but it seems that `withTimeoutOrNull` provides a scope. Should I wrap it somewhere?

Comment: Yeah I get it and I think you are right and `withTimeoutOrNull` indeed provides scope, my bad :)